# Get array key value with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, swift3, alamofire

I am making a simple request to get specific data from a JSON file, but I am having issues getting the exact data.

The JSON file:

```
{
    "Something1": {
        "Added": "09-10-2016",
        "Expires": "09-12-2016",
        "Reliability": "78%",
        "Views": "2",
        "Priority": "High"
    },
    "Something2": {
        "Added": "09-11-2016",
        "Expires": "09-13-2016",
        "Reliability": "98%",
        "Views": "5",
        "Priority": "Low"
    }
}
```

The swift code:

```
Alamofire.request("https://example.com/args.json").responseJSON { response in
            if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                print(JSON["Something1"])
            }
        }
```

With `print(JSON["Something1"])`, it prints everything for Something1 just like it's supposed to but an error is thrown when I try to do `print(JSON["Something1"]["Views"])` for example. How would I go about fixing this?

Comment: i think you have to to cast your JSON["Something1"] as a [String:AnyObject]

Comment: @koropok That definitely did it for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem isn't related to Alamofire I'm afraid, it's more of deal with JSON using Swift. In your case when you make your first optional binding you're converting to a `[String: AnyObject]` and it's correct and this implies that you can subscript `JSON["Something1"]`.

But after that when you try to subscript again over the `JSON["Something1"]["Views"]` the compiler doesn't know what have the `JSON["Something1"]` so you can't using as a dictionary instead you need to cast it again to a dictionary because is nested using optional binding like this:

```
if let nestedDictionary1 = JSON["Something1"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
    // access individual value in dictionary

    if let views = nestedDictionary1["Views"] as? Int {
         print(views)
    }
}
```

You can read more about the work with JSON in this [article](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37) of Apple.

I hope this help you.